# Sum all the fields in documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents with a number of tokens in text, one document for a text. I need to calculate a total token count across documents. I don't know the exact number and keys of these fields, so I cannot use $sum for each field individually.

For example, I have two documents:

```
{
    "count": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 5,
        "c": 7
    }
}

{
    "count": {
        "a": 4,
        "c": 2,
        "d": 6
    }
}
```

I want to aggregate them and get

```
{
    "count": {
        "a": 5,
        "b": 5,
        "c": 9,
        "d": 6
    }
}
```

As I understand, it is not possible, but I just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $set: {
  count: {
    "$objectToArray": "$count"
  }
}
},
{
  $unwind: "$count"
},
{
  $group: {
  _id: "$count.k",
  v: {
    $sum: "$count.v"
  }
 }
 },
{
$project: {
  v: 1,
  k: "$_id",
  _id: 0
 }
},
{
$group: {
  _id: "total",
  count: {
    $push: {
      k: "$k",
      v: "$v"
     }
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
  _id: 0,
  count: {
    "$arrayToObject": "$count"
   }
  }
}
])
```

Explained:

1. Convert the objects to array(to be easy to manipulate unknown number of fields )
2. Unwind the array
3. group by the keys , sum the values.
4. project the necessary key / values.
5. group all in single array
6. Project to convert the array to object as per the expectations

[Playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9HYhxdBbk-5)

---

Version 2 ( Without unwind ):

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {
  $set: {
   count: {
    "$objectToArray": "$count"
    }
   }
 },
 {
  "$group": {
     "_id": "test",
    count: {
    "$push": "$count"
    }
  }
  },
  {
   $set: {
  count: {
    $reduce: {
      input: {
        $concatArrays: "$count"
      },
      initialValue: [],
      in: {
        $setUnion: [
          "$$this",
          "$$value"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
 }
 },
 {
  "$addFields": {
    "count": {
    "$arrayToObject": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$count",
        "as": "m",
        "in": {
          "k": "$$m.k",
          "v": {
            "$sum": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$count",
                "as": "d",
                "in": {
                  "$cond": [
                    {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$$d.k",
                        "$$m.k"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$d.v",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
   }
  }
 ])
```

Explained:

1. Convert object to array to be easier later
2. Group in single document with push
3. Concat the arrays to single array
4. Using two nested $map's group & $sum inside the k/v array and convert back to object.

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RpxSRiFXcXj)